# Access json objects using a python generator

Tags: python

This is a sample of an export of my sql table(27 million rows) as follows :

`test.json`

```
{
    "table": "table",
    "rows":
    [
        {
            "state": "UNKNOWN"
        },
        {
            "state": "IE"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the generator function I am trying to use to load the table in elasticsearch

```
filename='test.json'
def load_json(filename):
    with open(filename,'r') as open_file:
        yield json.load(open_file)['rows']
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: pop() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

[image]

On running `next(load_json(filename))` on my generator function , this  the output.

```
[{'state': 'UNKNOWN'}, {'state': 'IE'}]
```

As you can see it is returning a `list`, which is causing the error.

Can someone please explain how I can access my json correctly and why my approach is incorrect.

Comment: where is the `pop()`, is that the full error?

Comment: @KuldeepSinghSidhu I guess he want to use the `dict.pop` but he yield a list from json file --- he just yield dict['rows'] instead of a full dict

Comment: And, to be honest, I can't find any reason that you should use generator at this point. A return statement is good enough.

Comment: I have 27 million rows to load in elasticsearch, thats why using generator. @YangHG

Comment: @MurtazaHaji OK, now I can write an answer for you.

Comment: I am new to generators , hence asked this question. Please state reason if you are trying to downvote this question. I followed all the guidelines for asking an appropriate question.

Comment: @MurtazaHaji I din't downvote you, but I think I know the reason --- you didn't show where is actually the error raised. I can guess what do you want to do, but someone can't. When you ask a new question, you should show all the important lines. And, I see you upload a image, but I can't load it. stackoverflow does not recommend anyone use image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You yield a list so you can't use `dict.pop`. In your case, you should write your code like this:

```
def load_json(file_name):
    with open(filename,'r') as open_file:
        for row in json.load(open_file)['rows']:
            yield row
```

That means, once you load a new row, you will jump out to other function to process the value. Then you could do pop below.

```
for row in load_json(file_name):
    print(row.pop('state'))
```

But, still want to let you know, this way can't optimize your code, because `json.load` will read the full file at once, so it will still consume a large memory...

You said you use elasticsearch, so you'd better use pagination itself instead of generator.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am trying to setup a pipeline for elasticsearch, but need to get the initial sql load in. I will split my file in smaller chunks using pandas incase I am not able to run this directly. Hopefully it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely want to iterate through rows and output them one by one like this:

```
filename='test.json'
def load_json(filename):
    with open(filename,'r') as open_file:
        for r in json.load(open_file)['rows']:
            yield r
```

Currently you just yield one thing - the whole list. So the iterator created by your original function will return a full list as first element and then will stop.